# Reference a dll inside a folder within the bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, vs-web-site-project

Inside my Bin folder I created another folder called "Template" (Bin > Template). Inside the Template folder I have a set of dll's, of which I would like to call from a class; like... `using Bin.Template.Example.ClassName;` Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: Right click project, Add Reference, Browse.

Comment: That's not how assembly names and namespaces work. Add a reference to the assembly, then add a `using` directive to import the namespace in the code file.

Comment: As @Chris Pickford suggested, I just needed to Add References the conventional way; my problem was that I was copying and pasting the dll's directly yo the folder. Thanks all for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `Assembly.LoadFile` to load external assemblies.

```
        var x = Assembly.LoadFile("myFile.dll");
        var myObject = x.CreateInstance("MyClass");
```

However you will not have strongly typed access to the resulting object.

Consider using dependency injection instead, where you will be able to load assemblies and know the types.

Comment: Using an interface  should give you some strong typing: `IFace myObject = (IFace)x.CreateInstance(..)`?

Comment: Yes provided the source and target assemblies share a common interface assembly they both reference.

Answer (score 0):

To use an external DLL from the filesystem, you need to add a reference at the project level. Right click `References` under your project, and choose `Add Reference...`:

[image]

Then click `Browse` button, locate the DLL, press `Ok`.

Inside your class file, add `using <dll.name.space>;` to the top.

Comment: I double checked my code, and what I intended to do, seems not to work that way... Inside the Bin folder I created a Template folder and Added the References the conventional way (Bin > Template > .dll), but what the system does is put the dll's  @ root of bin, not inside the Template folder...

Comment: You shouldn't be manually putting things in the bin folder, consider this volatile as it's contents should be managed by your build process. If you have a real need to put these referenced DLLs in a subfolder, script it as a post build event, but ensure you add the subfolder to your PATH.